# Redux remote devtools : Chrome inspector tab instead of separate window

Tags: react-native, redux

Currently the only way I can access the remote devtools in the **redux devtools chrome extension** is by opening a new window.

I know that for a current website, you can inspect the redux state in a Chrome inspector tab. Is there a way to do that for the remote devtools?